# When is it worth creating an XML Schema (XSD)?

Tags: html, xml, xsd, seo, schema.org

I'm curious of thoughts on how one would want to apply schema to a list of completed projects, for example, a listing of projects that were completed by an architecture firm.

So let's say you have a list of projects that were completed, consisting of information such as the date, location, description, etc.

I don't know if it is necessarily considered a Creative Work, or a place. I'm considering using the general ItemList/Item properties but not sure if there is much value in it. So having said that, would anyone expect this to be beneficial or worth doing?

Comment: Here is OP’s new question with almost the same body: [Applying RDFa to a list completed projects with location](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27894195/1591669)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged your question with [seo](/questions/tagged/seo) and [html](/questions/tagged/html), but those are not reasons to define an XML Schema (XSD).  You mention "Creative Work", but that concept is also immaterial to XSDs and their benefits.

### The Value of Defining an XSD

There is value in defining an XSD in so far as you, or the software you use, or the partners with whom you exchange data would benefit from the clear definition and automatic validation of structured documents.

If these reasons are not relevant to your work, you probably don't need to define an XSD.

Comment: Thank you, great answer to a dumb question. I obviously need to really think through before posting, I had somehow mixed up XML with RDFa