# Applying RDFa to a list completed projects with location

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, rdfa

How would someone apply schema to a list of completed projects, for example a listing of projects that were completed by an architecture firm.

Let's say you have a list of projects that were completed, consisting of information such as the date, location, description, etc.

I don't know if it is necessarily considered a CreativeWork or a Place. I'm considering using the general ItemList/Item properties but not sure if there is much value in it. So having said that, would anyone expect this to be beneficial or worth applying?

EDIT:

To elaborate, here is some code to correspond with the question:

```
<section class="work-listing">
    <h1>List of completed projects</h1>

    <article class="completed-work" vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="????">
        <h2 property="name">The Empire State Building</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><strong>Location</strong> New York, New York</li>
            <li><strong>Completed</strong> 2010</li>
            <li><strong>Architect</strong> William F. Lamb</li>
        </ul>
        <p property="about">The Empire State Building is a 103-story skyscraper located in Midtown Manhattan, New York City.</p>
    </article>

    <article class="completed-work" vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="??">...</article>
</section>
```

I've considered the following:

- Item
- Article
- CreativeWork
- Place
- Event

I feel like this situation calls for a little bit of each of these but wouldn't solely be categorized as any of them. I also am having a hard time on how I would write out some of the details of the projects, as that would rely on what's decided on for the parent.

Also, I know I used the ESB in the example above but the real projects wouldn't really fall into the HistoricalLandmarkorBuilding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone curious, I ended up going with Creative Work:

```
    <article class="completed-work" vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="CreativeWork">
        <h2 property="name">The Empire State Building</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><strong>Location</strong> <span property="contentLocation">New York, New York</li>
            <li><strong>Completed</strong> <span property="dateCreated">2010</span></li>
            <li><strong>Architect</strong> <span property="creator">William F. Lamb</span></li>
        </ul>
        <p property="description">The Empire State Building is a 103-story skyscraper located in Midtown Manhattan, New York City.</p>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are pages that you can emulate.

Use view-source.

[HTML pages codes in RDFa](http://www.ontomatica.com/public/organizations/ONTO/Intro.html)